# What is the best way to create user help documentation for an Excel VBA solution?

Tags: excel, officedev, vba

VBA solutions can vary widely in size.

I would like to add **user help** documentation to all solutions but the level of effort to create and deploy the **help** needs to match the size of the solution.

Comment: When you say help documentation to all solutions, are you refering to code commenting and documenting the code written, or help from user input point of view and helping him understand what fields need to be inputed

Answer (score 6):

You should check the [VBA version of MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx). It is an add-in for VBA that can automatically generate documentation from your code (function name, parameters, comments, subject, etc.). You can also use it to automatically generate line numbers, onError labels, etc. More on the automatic documenting feature can be found [here](http://www.mztools.com/v3/onlinehelp/index.html?html_xml_documentation.htm).

It is free, easy, and very efficient. Once you notice how much you save time by using it, please do like me: donate.

Comment: <http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx>

Comment: The MZ-Tools documentation feature is very good, but aimed at documenting the code.  
I am looking for solutions to create and deliver end user help documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider [HTML Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms669985.aspx). It allows you to produce help files that are similar to standard Microsoft help. It is not particularly difficult to use, for the most part.